# Drupal 8 Attached library to a paragraph

Tags: drupal-8

How can I attached a library to an specific paragraph? This is what I have so far.

```
function THEME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables){
    $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];
    $parentBundle = $paragraph->getParentEntity()->bundle();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still looking for an answer, you can easily do this via twig. Just create a twig template per paragraph, and add this: `{{ attach_library('theme/library') }}`.

You could do this via your .theme file as well, but that might be overkill for what you need.